# finding the tomcat installation directory

Tags: tomcat

I get the following message when I access IP provided by my ISP.

```
If you're seeing this page via a web browser, it means you've setup Tomcat successfully. Congratulations!

As you may have guessed by now, this is the default Tomcat home page. It can be found on the local filesystem at:

$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/index.html

where "$CATALINA_HOME" is the root of the Tomcat installation directory.
```

I want to change this default index.html page. Is there any one unix command to find the location of this index.html?

EDIT:
I located the ROOT folder. Another issue that I am facing is that my PHP page does not work here. But if I use php phppage.php at command line, it does work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/`

to display it, or

`cd $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ROOT/`

to change to the directory.

Comment: # bash: cd: /webapps/ROOT/: No such file or directory # The variable does not seem to be set

Comment: That stinks, and it does happen.Is this a shared host? You could run `find / -type d -name webapps`. This may take a LONG time, and your permissions on the server may cause a lot of errors to be thrown, but ultimately, it should find it.

Comment: @GregoryHoerner, you car hide the errors with: `find / -type d -name webapps 2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP page does not work because Tomcat does not run PHP pages; it is a Java servlet container.